# Log4J2 Relative path

Tags: java, maven, path, log4j, log4j2

I have problem with saving log file in Log4j2.

When I describe absolute path to directory for RollingFile within my project like "C:\Users\myuser\eclipse-workspace\app\src\main\resources\logs", file is succesfully creating, all logs are recording.

When I describe relative path to directory like "./logs/trace.txt", I get the error written below, though it is basically the same directory. It happens even if I set "fileName" just like "trace.txt" without any paths.

How to fix it? Maybe it connected to the fact it is a web project deploying on Tomcat...

```
    2020-08-11 14:35:40,267 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR Unable to create file trace_11_08_2020.log java.io.IOException: Access denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:574)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:554)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:131)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:60)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:952)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:892)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:884)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:508)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:232)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:244)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:261)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:239)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.initializeNonJndi(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:174)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.start(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:112)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(Log4jServletContainerInitializer.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2020-08-11 14:35:40,283 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR Unable to inject fields into builder class for plugin type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender, element RollingFile. java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@81d52be] unable to create manager for [trace_11_08_2020.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@3d033b58[pattern=trace_11_08_2020.log.zip, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=10485760)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=42, useMax=true), advertiseURI=null, layout=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-21t] %-5level{ERROR=***ERROR***} %-10marker %l - %m%n]]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:131)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:60)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:952)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:892)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:884)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:508)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:232)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:244)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:261)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:239)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.initializeNonJndi(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:174)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.start(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:112)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(Log4jServletContainerInitializer.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2020-08-11 14:35:40,289 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile. java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:130)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:952)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:892)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:884)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:508)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:232)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:244)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:261)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:239)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.initializeNonJndi(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:174)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.start(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:112)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(Log4jServletContainerInitializer.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My log4j2 configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="rootpath"></Property>
  </Properties>
  
  <CustomLevels>
    <CustomLevel name="HTTP" intLevel="50" />
  </CustomLevels>
  
  <Appenders>
  
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-21t] %-5level %-10marker %l - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    
    <RollingFile name="FileTrace" ignoreExceptions="false" fileName="${rootpath}trace_${date:dd_MM_yyyy}.log" filePattern="${rootpath}trace_${date:dd_MM_yyyy}.log.zip">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-21t] %-5level{ERROR=***ERROR***} %-10marker %l - %m%n"/>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="42" />
    </RollingFile>
    
    <RollingFile name="FileError" ignoreExceptions="false" fileName="${rootpath}error_trace_${date:dd_MM_yyyy}.log" filePattern="${rootpath}error_trace_${date:dd_MM_yyyy}.log.zip">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-21t] %-5level %l %rEx{full} %n"/>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="42" />
      <ThresholdFilter level="HTTP" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    </RollingFile>
    
    <RollingFile name="FileHTTP" ignoreExceptions="false" fileName="${rootpath}http_trace_${date:dd_MM_yyyy}.log" filePattern="${rootpath}http_trace_${date:dd_MM_yyyy}.log.zip">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-21t] %-5level %-10marker - %m%n"/>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="42" />
      <ThresholdFilter level="HTTP" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
    </RollingFile>
    
  </Appenders>
  
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="ALL">
      <AppenderRef ref="FileTrace" level="TRACE"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="FileError" level="ERROR"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="FileHTTP" level="HTTP"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
  
</Configuration>
```

My log4j2 dependencies:

```
<dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
             <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
             <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
            
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
             <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
             <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
          </dependency>
```

Comment: UPD: details added

Comment: It obviously some permission issue. if you create a folder and set it as the directory for file creation you won't have any issue. I am assuming when you start the process it tries to create your log file in some weird directory like C:/Windows/System32...